# Using scope variable as argument in scope function in expression

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I have in my controller:

```
$scope.arg = 1;
$scope.func = function(num) {
   return num;
}
```

How could I use the function in an expression in the html while using the variable as the argument?

I tried this:

```
{{ func(arg) }}
```

and:

```
{{ func($scope.arg) }}
```

Neither of these worked.

Comment: `{{ func(arg) }}` will work. Verify there is no js error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly use function in expression:

```
$scope.func = function(num) {
   return num;
}
```

HTML

```
{{ func(arg) }}
```

This will definately work